# Angular - Best way to simulate realtime with web api

Tags: angular, web-services, http, real-time

What is the best way to simulate real time with angular app and web api restful.

I explain myself I have a service that sends me a list of objects. it's objects are shared by all users of the web application. So it can create delete objects or change the status of an object.

To ensure the consistency of data presented to users I perform permanent polling every 300ms I make a get request. I compare my new table to update the status, delete or add the objects. I do not perform a direct assignment otherwise the user experience is degraded because html elements will have null values.
But I ask what are the best practices in this case, what tips can I apply?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If you have events to transfer in one direction from server to the client you can use SSE (server sent event) using http, if you want bi-directional use web sockets:

- you implement SSE on your Backend
- on your angular you can subscribe to channel and wait for data
- you can create an Observable for each type of event
- or you can use ngrx store, when you receive a new event, you can dispatch an action that will set the new state and update your view automatically

in case of [serviceStack](https://servicestack.net/), i have an angular service, inside receivers i dispatch action and update the store and my view my view :

```
createSseClient(channels: string[]) {
  this.sseClient = new ServerEventsClient(this.sseServer, channels, {
    handlers: {},
    receivers: {
    MyReciver: {
      SendMagnetNotif //method: (notif: any) => {
        this.store.dispatch(new notificationActions.AddNotification(notif)); // update ngrx store and the view
      }
    }
    ...
 },
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for you repIy, i should have specified but I want to manage this situation only by the application angular (it imposes me ..) But thank you for your answer in case of future evolution I will try to implement what you propose. I hesitate between a SignalR overlay or implement SSE for my API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Socket.io to establish a websocket connection from your angular app. 
In the following link, there is a detailed example of building socket.io and angular based real time app.

https://auth0.com/blog/real-time-charts-using-angular-d3-and-socket-io/

For C# based backend , you can use SignalR.

https://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: Thanks for you repIy, i should have specified but I want to manage this situation only by the application angular (it imposes me ..) But thank you for your answer in case of future evolution I will try to implement what you propose. I hesitate between a SignalR overlay or implement SSE for my API.